# jQuery Fade in FadeOut Issue in User Control

Tags: jquery

I have a user control,  `<asp:  Button>` inside it. On button click I am trying to populate message  in label  to fadein and fade out. The label is in default.aspx page. Where the user control is place in the default.aspx.

Used the following code to run jQuery for fadein fadeout. But some how the fadein fade out is not working as this is in user control as the function is not fired.  If it is in the same page. Function is getting fired.

```
public void AssignData(string strMsg)
{
    if (strMsg == "No Results")
        lblMsgText.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    else
        lblMsgText.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;

    lblMsgText.Text = strMsg;
    RunJavaScriptVallidations();
}

/// <summary>
/// This method is used for validations.
/// </summary>
public void RunJavaScriptVallidations()
{
    string strJavaScript = @"$('#tcPatients_tbsearch_Search1_btnSearch').click(function(){     
            $('#" + lblMsgText.ClientID + @"').fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(2000);
      });";

    ToolkitScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, GetType(), "Validations", strJavaScript, true);
}
```

`RunJavaScriptVallidations();` - this method is called in page load.

Any thoughts on how to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: hi user , please try to change the design. The html should not club with code behind file above , please separate the UI and business logic , your user control should have html in ascx  file and then create a separate javascript file to handle all click events.

Answer (score 1):

You need to hook up to the ID of the button in *this* control, which is going to change depending on where the user control it, so use `ClientID`, like this:

```
public void RunJavaScriptVallidations()
{
    string strJavaScript = @"$('#" + btnSearch.ClientID + @"').click(function(){     
            $('#" + lblMsgText.ClientID + @"').fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(2000);
      });";

    ToolkitScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "Validations", strJavaScript, true);
}
```

Also use `this` instead of `Page` so it's registered for *this* UserControl, not once for the page.